# Se alcanzó el límite de archivos de 100 archivos en el directorio 'D: \ S3 \'

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Buen Dia colegas Mi problema es el siguiente

Estoy Utilizando el servicio de S3 con RDS

tengo una duda al respecto de esta leyenda:

```
[2021-10-13 18:33:22.107] Task aborted. [2021-10-13 18:33:22.110] Reached file limit of 100 files in the 'D:\S3\' directory.
```

Se que se alcanzo el limite pero no entiendo , es por día? por mes se suponía que era ilimitado

Edit :

Tengo una instancia con rds y desde sql subo archivos hacia s3

Subía archivos con normalidad hasta que me salio el mensaje del error

Ejecutando este query :    `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(NULL,127);`

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esta duda De antemano Gracias

Comment: Este mensaje quién lo entrega, RDS o S3? No sabemos qué intentas y eso hace difícil ayudarte a interpretar un mensaje. S3 no tiene límite en lo que guardas en un bucket; no sabemos es si hay quotas definidas o si estás fijando cada cosa en un bucket diferente (esos sí tienen límite por cuenta), no sabemos si es un límite de RDS, etc. Por favor, sé más específico en el detalle del problema

Comment: hola @Alfabravo ya edite la pregunta y no ,no tengo una cuota definida y todo se guarda en el mismo bucket

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación oficial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html) dice:

> Downloading to the DB instance is limited to 100 files. In other words, there can't be more than 100 files in D:\S3.

Que en traducción libre, significa que tienes un límite estricto de 100 archivos en esa ruta. No es un límite de S3 per sé, sino una limitación en la integración.

Ahí mismo también indican que cada archivo está limitado a 50GB, para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Comment: Gracias por comentar , Entiendo , so sabia que solo admitía 100 por ruta

Comment: Sabes donde podría meter mas de  100 archivos? que no sea D:\S3?

Comment: Lo siento, no conozco más detalles de esta integración